# get response from webserver with ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongoose

i am beginner in ajax and i decided to use jquery ajax for this moment , and before using ajax i created simple login / signup pages and i used bodyparser for requests 
and when password or username is incorrect it reloads and then sends response to user that one of them is incorrect, and as i know ajax works without reload and
how can i add ajax when info is incorrect while login here is code

```
app.post('/login',
async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ username, password }).select('-password').lean();
        if (!user) {
            res.send('User: ' + username + ' not registered');
            return;
        }

        req.session.user = user; 
        res.redirect('/dash')  
        return res.status(200).send('Session ID: ' + req.sessionID);


    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

```
$('#login-button').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var username = $('#username').val(), password = $('#password').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/login',
    success: function(sessionID) {
      console.log(sessionID);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      var errMsg = xhr.responseText; // Your error msg
      $('#errMsg').html(errMsg);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: is it safe to get users password in frontend javascript code?

Comment: yes. that is the password the user typed in the password field in your form.

Comment: unless you are particularly expecting a certain kind of data type from the server, it's an optional field and can be omitted. jQuery will automatically try to infer the data type. Please have a look at the  [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: yes that is safe. Once your site has the encrypted connection setup ie. SSL (https://), the data that you are sending is encrypted.